# Configure a separate Grunt instance in a test

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, integration-testing

I have been writing a small grunt plugin, and now I am stuck trying to test the plugin end-to-end. What I would like to accomplish is this

- Write a test case that configures a grunt instance with a minimal grunt config for my plugin and runs that task
- Test that the file produced equals the intended output
- Run that test automatically when running `grunt nodeunit`

So far, I seem stuck on configuring an individual Grunt instance, as the new instance seems to share configuration with that of the already loaded Grunt instance.

I got something like this in my `plugin_test.js`

```
var testGrunt = require('grunt');

exports.codekit = {
    setUp: function(done) {

        testGrunt.initConfig({
          myPlugin : {
            // the config
          }
        });

        testGrunt.task.run(['myPlugin']);
        done();
    },

    basic_parsing_works: function(test) {
      test.expect(1); // no idea what this does

      test.equal(1,1,'basic test');
      //var actual = testGrunt.file.read('tmp/test01_result.html');
      //var expected = testGrunt.file.read('expected/test01_expected.html');
      //test.equal(actual, expected, 'should parse file.');

      test.done();
    }
};
```

The problem is that when I run the task for `myPlugin` it uses the configuration loaded in the "outer" (already running) Grunt instance. Even though I have specifically created a new Grunt instance under a different name (`testGrunt`).

Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Spawn Grunt tasks in new process](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25455742/spawn-grunt-tasks-in-new-process)