# Spawn Grunt tasks in new process

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

I have been using [grunt-execute](https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-execute) to launch my app.js node server.

I also have a grunt watch task.

Both of these tasks don't end, they just sit there waiting. The problem is that I need to start both of them.

Can I start one in a separate process, or thread (I don't know the correct term) so they can both run at the same time?

I have tried [grunt-spawn](https://github.com/fir3pho3nixx/grunt-spawn) and [grunt-shell-spawn](https://github.com/cri5ti/grunt-shell-spawn) but the don't actually launch a separate thing, so the second task never gets run. If I start with the watch, the server never gets executed, if I start with the server, the watch never runs.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[grunt-concurrent](https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-concurrent) enables you to run multiple blocking tasks at once!